# How can I build a redirect from submitted form values?

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

I'm working on a short weather app.

What I want to do, is to catch name of the input of city and redirect users to the city's page URL after submit.

```
function form_findYourCity_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $city = $form_state['values']['city_name'];

  // catching city name from input and assigning it to a variable
}
```

And I want after submit redirect user to new page with `url/something/?city=something` on which I then want to use if `isset $_GET['city']` and then do my operations with the weather API database and pulling data based on the city.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have figured it out by myself.

Here is what I needed:

```
function form_findYourCity_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $city = $form_state['values']['city_name'];

  $form_state['redirect'] = [
    'showCity',
    [
      'query' => [
        'city' => $city,
      ],
    ],
  ];

}
```